# Zip a Directory and not Have the Result Saved in File System

Tags: go, zip, filesystems, gzip

I am able to zip a file using logic similar to the zip writer seen [here](https://golang.org/src/archive/zip/example_test.go).

This results in an array of bytes (`[]byte`) being created within the `bytes.Buffer` object that is returned. I would just like to know if there is there any way I can upload this 'zipped' array of bytes to an API endpoint that expects a 'multipart/form-data' request body (without having to save it locally).

Supplementary information:

I have code that utilizes [this](https://golangcode.com/create-zip-files-in-go/) when compressing a folder. I am able to successfully execute an HTTP POST request with the zip file to the endpoint with this logic.

However, this unfortunately saves zipped files in a user's local file system. I would like to try to avoid this :)

Comment: Is your problem that the zip file stays in the file system? If so, you can always deleted it once you're done uploading it. Or you could create the zip file in the OS's temporary directory and leave it to the OS to remove it automatically.

Comment: I would like to try to not have the zip file stay in the file system period :) Kinda of like a 'zip stream' (I think this is the right term)

Comment: In the second example code you can replace `newZipFile, err := os.Create(filename)` with `buf := new(bytes.Buffer)` from the first example and then use `buf` instead of `newZipFile` to create the writer, i.e. `zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multipart writer and write []byte zipped data into field with field name you like and file name like below.

```
func addZipFileToReq(zipped []byte)  (*http.Request, error){
    body := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(`fileField`, `filename`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    _, err = part.Write(zipped)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    r, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "https://example.com", body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    r.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    return r, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream-upload the zip, you should be able to do so with [`io.Pipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe). The following is an incomplete and untested example to demonstrate the general idea. To make it work you'll need to modify it and potentially fix whatever bugs you encounter.

```golang
func UploadReader(r io.Reader) error {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "<UPLOAD_URL>", r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // TODO set necessary headers (content type, auth, etc)

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else if res.StatusCode != 200 {
        return errors.New("not ok")
    }
    return nil
}
```

```golang
func ZipDir(dir string, w io.Writer) error {
    zw := zip.NewWriter(w)
    defer zw.Close()

    return filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            return nil
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(fi)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        header.Name = path
        header.Method = zip.Deflate

        w, err := zw.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        f, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer f.Close()

        if _, err := io.Copy(w, f); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

```golang
func UploadDir(dir string) error {
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    ch := make(chan error)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer w.Close()

        if err := ZipDir(dir, w); err != nil {
            ch <- err
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer r.Close()

        if err := UploadReader(r); err != nil {
            ch <- err
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    return <-ch
}
```